# Gmail API multiple accounts

Tags: javascript, authentication, oauth-2.0, gmail-api

I have 4 gmails accounts, I am building a dashboard sort of web page, where i want to show number of unread mails in all of 4 mails. But When I auth with one account it doesn't displays the count of other accounts.

Is there any method to keep multiple accounts signed in?

I want output like;

**Mail 1:    10 unread Mails**

**Mail 2:    9  unread mails**
so on....

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can do it on storing the Credential for each count, for example :

```
if(Session["Credentials"]==null)
    List<UserCredential> Credentials= new List<UserCredential>();
esle
   List<UserCredential> Credentials=(List<UserCredential>)Session["Credentials"];

    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                             new ClientSecrets
                             {
                                 ClientId = "Client_ID",
                                 ClientSecret = "Client_Secret"
                             },
                             Scopes,
                             "me",
                             CancellationToken.None,
                             new FileDataStore(path)

                             ).Result;
Credentials.Add(Credential); 
Session["Credentials"]=Credentials;
```

note : you need to clear the file data wich contain ResponseToken for each authentification.

Comment: Do you have any idea how it will work with javascript ?
How to access Client id and secret for each account?

Comment: The client ID and secret client are related to the project which you create for authentification. you juste need to store the ResponseToken.

Comment: i will do a test with java script and I give you the answer soon

Comment: yeah, pls note I want to avoid repeated auth, i want to Auth only once  (for all acoounts) , and then I will show count refreshing after 10 or 20seconds.

Comment: any luck? can you guide me how to  keep all mails logged in simultaneously?